# Datatables - Fixed column with two multiple headers

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatable with two headers and one fixed column. The requirement is to keep the first column fixed while allowing the other columns to scroll.

The problem is the second header works correctly, but the first header scrolls over the second column. Is there a way to make sure that both headers for the first column remain fixed? Thanks.

Here is my example -
https://live.datatables.net/nupawudi/1/edit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        scrollY: "300px",
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        fixedColumns: {
          left: 1}
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/4.1.0/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css"
    />

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/4.1.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"
    ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="table.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid"><thead>
<tr>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" white-space: nowrap;">Col1</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" white-space: nowrap;">Col2</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" white-space: nowrap;">Col3</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" white-space: nowrap;">Col4</th>
<th>Col5</th>

</tr>

<tr>
<th style=" background-color: lightgray; width: 35px; min-width: 220px; text-align: left;">Test1</th>
<th style=" background-color: lightgray;">Test2</th>
<th>Test3</th>
<th>Test4</th>
<th>Test5</th>
<th>Test6</th>
<th>Test7</th>
<th>Test8</th>
<th>Test9</th>
<th>Test10</th>
<th>Test11</th>
<th>Test12</th>
<th>Test13</th>
<th>Test14</th>
<th>&#160;</th>

</tr>

</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>One</td>
<td><strong>John</strong></td>
<td><strong>Yes</strong></td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>Two</td>
<td><strong>Julie</strong></td>
<td><strong>Yes</strong></td>
<td><strong>Yes</strong></td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>Three</td>
<td><strong>Joe</strong></td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td><strong>Yes</strong></td>
<td><strong>Yes</strong></td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>Four</td>
<td><strong>Shiny</strong></td>
<td><strong>Yes</strong></td>
<td><strong>Yes</strong></td>
<td><strong>Yes</strong></td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>
<td style=" text-align: center;">&#160;</td>

</tr>



       
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want the second column to be fixed as well?

Comment: No, I want both the headers for first column to remain fixed.  The second header (with Test1, Tes2 columns) works fine, but not the first header (Col1, Col2 etc.).

Comment: Since you are using the external plug-in DataTables, I suggest you seek support from their website, as this does not seem to be a very popular plug-in that many are familiar with. I personally cannot help you and no one else seems to have pitched in yet, so you may find an answer on their support forums quicker.

Comment: Thankyou. I reached out to them and they responded. It seems they do not support multiple headers. So I ended up merging the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to Datatables team and they responded. It seems they do not support multiple headers.

My solution was to merge the headers. Thanks.